# What is thread safe (C#) ? (Strings, arrays, ... ?)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, thread-safety, enumeration

I'm quite new to C# so please bear with me. I'm a bit confused with the thread safety. When is something thread safe and when something isn't?

Is **reading** (just reading from something that was initialized before) from a field always thread safe?

```
//EXAMPLE
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACrytoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(xmlString);  
//Is this thread safe if xml String is predifined 
//and this code can be called from multiple threads?
```

Is **accessing** an object from an array or list always thread safe (in case you use a for loop for enumeration)?

```
//EXAMPLE (a is local to thread, array and list are global)
int a = 0;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  a += array[i];
  a -= list.ElementAt(i);
}
```

Is **enumeration** always/ever thread safe?

```
//EXAMPLE
foreach(Object o in list)
{
   //do something with o
 }
```

Can **writing and reading** to a particular field ever result in a corrupted read (half of the field is changed and half is still unchanged) ?

Thank you for all your answers and time.

**EDIT:** I meant if all threads are only reading & using (not writing or changing) object. (except for the last question where it is obvious that I meant if threads both read and write). Because I do not know if plain access or enumeration is thread safe.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's different for different cases, but in general, reading is safe if all threads are reading.  If any are writing, neither reading or writing is safe unless it can be done atomically (inside a synchronized block or with an atomic type).

It isn't definite that reading is ok -- you never know what is happening under the hoods -- for example, a getter might need to initialize data on first usage (therefore writing to local fields).

For Strings, you are in luck -- they are immutable, so all you can do is read them.  With other types, you will have to take precautions against them changing in other threads while you are reading them.

Answer (score 13):

> Is reading (just reading from something that was initialized before) from a field always thread safe?

The C# language guarantees that reads and writes are consistently ordered when the reads and writes are on a single thread in section 3.10:

---

> Data dependence is preserved within a thread of execution. That is, the value of each variable is computed as if all statements in the thread were executed in original program order. Initialization ordering rules are preserved.

---

**Events in a multithreaded, multiprocessor system do not necessarily have a well-defined consistent ordering in time with respect to each other.**  The C# language does not guarantee there to be a consistent ordering. A sequence of writes observed by one thread may be observed to be in a completely different order when observed from another thread, so long as no critical execution point is involved.

The question is therefore unanswerable because it contains an undefined word. Can you give a *precise* definition of what "before" means to you with respect to events in a multithreaded, multiprocessor system?

The language guarantees that side effects are ordered only with respect to critical execution points, and even then, does not make any strong guarantees when exceptions are involved. Again, to quote from section 3.10:

---

> Execution of a C# program proceeds such that the side effects of each executing thread are preserved at critical execution points. A side effect is defined as a read or write of a volatile field, a write to a non-volatile variable, a write to an external resource, and the throwing of an exception. The critical execution points at which the order of these side effects must be preserved are references to volatile fields, lock statements, and thread creation and termination. [...] The ordering of side effects is preserved with respect to volatile reads and writes.
>
> Additionally, the execution environment need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that that expression’s value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a method or accessing a volatile field). When program execution is interrupted by an asynchronous event (such as an exception thrown by another thread), it is not guaranteed that the observable side effects are visible in the original program order.

---

> Is accessing an object from an array or list always thread safe (in case you use a for loop for enumeration)?

By "thread safe" do you mean that two threads will always observe consistent results when reading from a list?  As noted above, the C# language makes very limited guarantees about observation of results when reading from variables. Can you give a precise definition of what "thread safe" means to you with respect to non-volatile reading?

> Is enumeration always/ever thread safe?

Even in single threaded scenarios it is illegal to modify a collection while enumerating it. It is certainly unsafe to do so in multithreaded scenarios.

> Can writing and reading to a particular field ever result in a corrupted read (half of the field is changed and half is still unchanged) ?

Yes. I refer you to section 5.5, which states:

---

> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type in the previous list are also atomic. Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic. Aside from the library functions designed for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or decrement.

---

Comment: By "before" I mean that something was initialized before threads were started. By "thread safe" I meant if many threads can enumerate and/or iterate through same objects (arrays, lists,... <-they are initialized and filled "before") and just read from them without problems?

Comment: @Ben: if there is a thread start in there then there is a critical execution point, and therefore the observable side effects are guaranteed to be ordered with respect to that critical point.

Comment: There is no guarantee that a long/ulong read/write on a 64-bit architecture is atomic?

Comment: @James: The language specification has nothing to say on the subject of 64 bit hardware. All it says is that 32 bit variables and reference-sized variables must be guaranteed to be atomic for an implementation to be conforming. If you personally happen to be running a C# program on hardware that makes a stronger guarantee, then that guarantee is provided to you by your hardware vendor, not by your friendly neighbourhood C# compiler provider. I'm not going to make any claims on behalf of unknown hardware manufacturers.

Comment: Similarly, the x86 memory model is far, far stronger than the memory model I outlined above. The x86 hardware vendors are making promises that they claim to deliver on; the C# language certainly makes no promises on behalf of the x86 hardware vendors. If you choose to rely on promises made to you by hardware vendors, that's your business.

Comment: Furthermore, the *CLI* specification does promise that all data structures have atomicity if they are native-word-sized or less and their addresses are aligned to word boundaries. (And it promises that you don't get misalignment by accident; you have to ask for it.) However, the C# language could be implemented to run on platforms other than implementations of the CLI.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I generally assume everything is thread unsafe.  For quick and dirty access to global objects in an threaded environment I use the *lock(object)* keyword.  .Net have an extensive set of synchronization methods like different semaphores and such.

Answer (score 3):

Reading *can* be thread-unsafe if there are any threads that are writing (if they write in the middle of a read, for example, they'll be hit with an exception).

If you must do this, then you can do:

```
lock(i){
    i.GetElementAt(a)
}
```

This will force thread-safety on i (as long as other threads similarly attempt to lock i before they use it.  only one thing can lock a reference type at a time.

In terms of enumeration, I'll refer to the MSDN:

```
The enumerator does not have exclusive access to the collection; therefore, enumerating 
through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. To guarantee thread 
safety during enumeration, you can lock the collection during the entire enumeration. To 
allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must     
implement your own synchronization.
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of no thread-safety: When several threads increment an integer. You can set it up in a way that you have a predeterminded number of increments. What youmay observe though, is, that the int has not been incremented as much as you thought it would. What happens is that two threads may increment the same value of the integer.This is but an example of aplethora of effects you may observe when working with several threads.

**PS**

A thread-safe increment is available through `Interlocked.Increment(ref i)`