# How is NET 4.0 SpinWait method different to pre-4.0 SpinWait()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, spinwait

MSDN ["Thread-Safe Collections .NET Framework 4"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) states:

> "Some of the concurrent collection types use lightweight
>   synchronization mechanisms such as [SpinLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), **SpinWait**,
>   [SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which are new in the .NET
>   Framework 4"

while MSDN website tells that [SpinWaitwas was available as far as .NET 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) while another MSDN article [starts SpinWaitwas from .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Well, the curiosity is from the comment by  Lee Grissom to answer [What is the difference between SynchronizedCollection and the other concurrent collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4655236/200449):

> "@Matt, the .NET4 concurrent classes use `SpinWait` objects to address
>   thread-safety instead of Monitor.Enter/Exit (aka Critical section)?"

as well as first NSDN quote stating that `SpinWait` is new to .NET 4.0

So, is it new or not?
And if new then how?

Comment: From looking at your links, and with no other knowledge, it seems that *a* `SpinWait` function was present in .NET 1.1 and the `SpinWait` structure was added in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The struct `System.Threading.SpinWait` is new to .NET 4.0. The method `System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait()` exists since .NET 1.0.

Note that `System.Threading.SpinWait` internally calls `System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait()`. For further details see "Concurrent Programming On Windows" by Joe Duffy (chapter 14, section "Spin Waiting").

Comment: Oh, [again that book](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15110525/2031316). No more .NET books on concurrency, just one?

Answer (score 8):

The [`System.Threading.SpinWait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait.aspx) **structure**  was introduced into .NET 4. The `System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait` **method** has been present since .NET 1.0.

From the docs for the `SpinWait` structure:

> SpinWait is not generally useful for ordinary applications. In most cases, you should use the synchronization classes provided by the .NET Framework, such as Monitor. For most purposes where spin waiting is required, however, the `SpinWait` type should be preferred over the `SpinWait` method.

Note the part that says you shouldn't be using either of them in most cases :)

Comment: Looks to me like all answers about thread-safety are thread-unsafe. Conspirating to deter me from multithreading progranning