# Create a asynchronous - singletone WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, service

What is the **best** way to create a `WCF service` that will work for a number of clients but will provide equivalent information stored on the Service?

I tried the following way:

```
[ServiceBehavior (ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

But because service it singletone it works very slow (probably it synchronous) when there are more than three clients.

But I need that service will be singletone, because I have an object that suppose to gave the same information to all clients (**or there is another way to do this?**)

**I would love to have other offers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to lock the use of the object itself,
or the critical section of the code.
There is no need to make the entire service singleton.
However, without seeing the code it is hard to know if this will help.
(Because if the long calculations are inside the critical section locking will not be helpful).

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify my answer, your problem has nothing to do with WCF.
You are really asking if you should pay the costs in complexity of the code
in order to get better performance, or stick with a single thread handeling of this section of the code. You would face the exact same issue if the call to the service was made from the same process (by different threads) and not from WCF client. So I suggest you read more about multi-threading and conecurrent collections before making up your mind.

Comment: My object is a list that is managed in service only. It changes by the various calls, but only in service. (It is private object)

Comment: Try replacing the list with a concurrent collection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106938/what-net-4-0-system-collections-concurrent-collection-added-in-functionality-to . If this is not an option, you will need to make sure all opeartions on the list are thread safe and face the possibility of race conditions , or stick with locking around every access to the list/using a singleton service